# I am trying to save images from my android app into microsoft sql server using C#

Tags: android

I am trying to save images from my android app into microsoft sql server using C#.Images are selected from phone gallery then i need to save that selected image using retrofit,
I have the code that selects from the phone, so i need the code that saves in sql server using C#.
I need both c# code and android.
Can any one help this issue"

Answer (score 0):

Android code to upload image using volley `VolleyMultipartRequest`.

```
 final File file = new File("Your image path here");


        final byte[] b = new byte[(int) file.length()];

        VolleyMultipartRequest multipartRequest = new VolleyMultipartRequest(Request.Method.POST, "url", new Response.Listener<NetworkResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                String resultResponse = new String(response.data);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "File uploaded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
                pd.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something went wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }) {


            @Override
            protected Map<String, DataPart> getByteData() {
                Map<String, DataPart> params = new HashMap<>();
                  params.put("Filename", new DataPart("file",b ));

                return params;
            }
        };

        GlobalClass.getmInstance().addToRequestQueue(multipartRequest);
```